# Show filename of error in popup in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: popup error]
At any file change this error appears and i don't know from where its generated or how to fix/hide it.

Any suggestion?

The error is not related to the opened file.. adding the filename can help me but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems related to an extension (maybe Angular?). You could try starting VS Code via command line with `--disable-extensions` param to be sure. It will start VS Code with no extension loaded. After that, if confirmed an extension error, open an issue in the respective repo.

About the message, it *should* be related to the focused file, but as you say it is not. In this case, it is probably related to the *previous* focused file, since the extensions uses a lot of assyncronous operations.